# VBA for sorting in excel in addition to current code to run for any worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I'm trying to add this VBA from a list of other commands however I'm getting an error. Please assist with the correct syntax for sort. thank you.

error message is: run-time error '1004' application-defined or object-defined error.

```
    Sub filter()
Dim N As Long
Dim wsName As String


For N = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    wsName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(N).Name

    If Len(wsName) = 3 Then

    Sheets(wsName).Range("$A$1:$XFC$1104").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=">=365" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd
    Sheets(wsName).Range("$A$1:$XFC$1104").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=">100" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd
    Sheets(wsName).Range("$A$1:$XFC$7606").AutoFilter Field:=20, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending _
        , Operator:=xlAnd
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("i_ULO").AutoFilter.sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With


    Else
end if 
next n
end sub
```

After adding this code below. New error came up.

```
Dim N As Long
```

Dim wsName As String

For N = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    wsName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(N).Name

```
If Len(wsName) = 3 Then
With .Cells(1, "A").CurrentRegion
     .Cells.sort Key1:=.Columns(20), Order1:=xlDescending, _
                 Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
End With
End With
```

[Compile Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coNSm.png)

[reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGixt.png)

Comment: `Field:=20.sort` can't be right - try changing that to `Field:=20`.

Comment: dwirony - after the edit new error message is run-time error '1004' application-defined or object-defined error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this VBA Sort code to sort the active worksheet's data table radiating out from A1 with column T as the primary sort key.

```
Dim N As Long 
Dim wsName As String 

For N = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count 
    wsName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(N).Name 
    If Len(wsName) = 3 Then 

        with ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(N)
            with .cells(1, "A").currentregion
                 .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(20), Order1:=xldescending, _
                             Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlyes
            end with
        end with

    end if
next n
```

Comment: Hi, I added your code to this and have the following error:                                                                                     Dim N As Long
Dim wsName As String
For N = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    wsName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(N).Name
    
    If Len(wsName) = 3 Then
    With .Cells(1, "A").CurrentRegion
         .Cells.sort Key1:=.Columns(20), Order1:=xlDescending, _
                     Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
    End With

Comment: compile error: invalid or unqualified reference                                                                                       highlights the .cells next to with.

Comment: `with ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(N).cells(1, "A").currentregion`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
Sub filter()

    Dim N As Long
    Dim wsName As String

    For N = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        wsName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(N).Name

        If Len(wsName) = 3 Then

            Sheets(wsName).Range("$A$1:$XFC$1104").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=">=365" _
                , Operator:=xlAnd
            Sheets(wsName).Range("$A$1:$XFC$1104").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=">100" _
                , Operator:=xlAnd
            Sheets(wsName).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("T1:T7606"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending

            With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("i_ULO").AutoFilter.Sort
                .Header = xlYes
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With

        End If

    Next N

End Sub
```